# I am getting " net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED" error after implementing post method in angular

Tags: angular, http-post, angular10

This is My Code.
This is Service Code in which I created a method for post method

```
Service Code

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


export interface Obj {
  userId?: number,
  title?: string,
  body?:string
}



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceService {

  url ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    
    }

    getPosts():Observable<Obj[]>{
     return this.http.get<Obj[]>(this.url)
    }

    createPost(fData:Obj){
      return this.http.post<Obj>(this.url,(fData));
    
   }
  }
```

This Component Code where I called the service

```
Component Code[enter image description here][1]

import { Obj } from './../service.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ServiceService } from '../service.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent {

  posts: Obj[] = [] ;


  constructor(private httpService:ServiceService){
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.httpService.getPosts().subscribe(response=>{
      this.posts = response;
      console.log(this.posts)}); 
    
  }
  addUser(data:HTMLInputElement){
    
    this.httpService.createPost(data).subscribe((response)=> {
      console.log(response);
  });
  
}
}
```

[Here is the image of the error I am Getting]([1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/psfQ5.jpg)

The Object is posted successfully in database when I try with local json server still getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this, it's worked for me

```
getPosts(parameter) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url, parameter);
}
```

Comment: Just change the variable name?